# How to click on the registration activation link in confirmation email, using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I simply want to click on the registration activation link provided in confirmation email.
I tried the following:

1st attempt

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'http://www.example.com/account/activate?')]")).click();
```

2nd Attempt

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("www.example.com/account/activate")).click();
```

Email is sent to mailinator.com

Some email content:

> Dear Valued Customer:
>
> Thank you and welcome to the Abc community!
>
> Simply click the following link to activate your account and get
>   started:
>   http://www.example.com/account/activate?userguid=4dbb9759-2c20-4cca-8168-9765fe1ce683
>
> As a Abc member you will benefit from a fantastic range of products
>   and tools including:

Comment: And what happens? What problem do you see?

Comment: Is it in an iframe? What email service you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try alternative search through css selector.
`*=`   when locating through CSS, equals to contains, i.e  `element[option1*="txt"]` means that element's option contains  "txt" pattern.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[a*=\"www.example.com/account/activate\"]")
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Following code worked. Mailinator has an iframe :) I missed it initially. I am new to Selenium

WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("account/activate?userguid")).click();